# OpenWRT with VLANs: NAT not working with single Firewall Rule

Tags: networking, firewall, nat, openwrt

I have a configuration on my OpenWrt Backfire 10.03 with different VLANs, `k2` belonging to `fwz2` is one of them. In this testing environment the `WAN` is DHCP with IP:192.168.1.1:

```
config 'interface' 'wan'
    option 'ifname' 'eth0.1'
    option 'proto' 'dhcp'
    option 'defaultroute' '0'
    option 'peerdns' '0'
config 'interface' 'k2'
    option 'proto' 'static'
    option 'ifname' 'eth0.3'
    option 'netmask' '255.255.255.0'
    option 'defaultroute' '0'
    option 'peerdns' '0'
    option 'ipaddr' '192.168.172.1'

config 'zone'
    option 'name' 'wan'
    option 'input' 'REJECT'
    option 'output' 'ACCEPT'
    option 'forward' 'REJECT'
    option 'masq' '1'
```

If have the the VLAN configured in the Firewall settings like

```
config 'forwarding'    #FWD-RULE#
    option 'src' 'fwz2'
    option 'dest' 'wan'
```

the NAT is working fine, however I want to only allow selected ports (e.g. ICMP):

```
config 'rule'          #ICMP-RULE#
    option 'target' 'ACCEPT'
    option '_name' 'fwz2-ICMP'
    option 'src' 'fwz2'
    option 'dest' 'wan'
    option 'proto' 'icmp'
```

I have in mind on a similar setup where I removed `#FWD-RULE#` and added `#ICMP-RULE#` and it works, but if I do this here, the NAT is not working anymore and gives me packets on the WAN interface like `IP 192.168.172.100 > 213.165.64.75: ICMP echo request`, if NAT would work, the src.addr `192.168.172.100` should be the translated to the WAN address.